# ¿Por qué react-native-file-viewer ya no abre archivos?

Tags: javascript, react-native

Tengo una aplicación en donde tengo la librería de react-native-file-viewer que funcionaba correctamente. Ahora parece que ya no distingue los archivos según el error que arroja; el archivo me lo genera correctamente, pero cuando intento abrir el archivo con una aplicación predeterminada me arroja el siguiente error:

> [Error: It wasn't possible to detect the type of the file]

```
// Con este código abría antes los archivos correctamente
static abirArchivoConAplicacionPredeterminada(url_archivo, nombre_pantalla = "Abrir con"){
        return new Promise((respuesta, rejected) => {
            console.log(`Dirección archivo para usar FileViewer: ${url_archivo}`);
            FileViewer.open(`${url_archivo}`, {
                displayName: nombre_pantalla,
                showAppsSuggestions: true,
            }).then(() => {
                respuesta(true);
            }).catch(err => {
                console.log(err);
                rejected("Error al intentar abrir archivo.");
            });
        });
    }
```

```
// Con este código genero archivos excel
static generarExcel(nombre_excel, nombre_hoja_excel, array_datos, compartir_archivo = false, abrir_archivo = false) {
        return new Promise((respuesta, rejected) => {
            if(Array.isArray(array_datos)){
                if(array_datos.length > 0){
                    // Ruta de guardado del archivo
                    const url_guardar = Utileria.DirectorioMAN + '/' + nombre_excel + ` ${AFechaUtil.obtenerFechaActualDDMMYYYY().replace(/\//gm, "")}_${AFechaUtil.obtenerHoraActualHHMMSS().replace(/\:/gm, "")}.xlsx`;
                    // Crear datos de un arreglo
                    let ws = XLSX.utils.json_to_sheet(array_datos);
                    // Crear la hoja de excel
                    let wb = XLSX.utils.book_new();
                    // Procesar y unir hoja de excel con los datos
                    XLSX.utils.book_append_sheet(wb, ws, nombre_hoja_excel);
                    // Escribir excel
                    const salidaExcel = XLSX.write(wb, {
                        type: "binary",
                        bookType: 'xlsx'
                    });

                    Utileria.tienePermisoEscritura()
                        .then(res => {
                            if (res) {

                                Utileria.verificarOCrearCarpetaExterna()
                                .then(res => {
                                    fs.writeFile(url_guardar, salidaExcel, "ascii")
                                    .then(async () => {
                                        if(compartir_archivo && !abrir_archivo){
                                            await Utileria.compartirArchivo(url_guardar, "Archivo excel generado a traves de Mi Asistente de Negocios");
                                        }

                                        if(abrir_archivo && !compartir_archivo){
                                            try {
                                                console.log(url_guardar);
                                                await Utileria.abirArchivoConAplicacionPredeterminada(url_guardar, "Abrir con");
                                            } catch (err) {
                                                rejected("Error al intentar abrir archivo excel, asegúrese que posea una aplicación para abrir archivos excel");
                                            }
                                        }

                                        respuesta([true, url_guardar]);
                                    }).catch(err => {
                                        //console.log(err);
                                        rejected("Error al crear archivo de excel.");
                                        //rejected(err);
                                    });
                                }).catch(err => {
                                    rejected("Error al crear carpeta para generar excel.");
                                });
                            }
                            else {
                                rejected("Permisos insuficientes para generar guardar reporte.");
                            }
                        }).catch(err => {
                            rejected("Error al consultar permisos del dispositivo, vuelva a intentarlo.");
                        });
                }
                else{
                    rejected("No se poseen datos para generar archivo excel en el rango de fechas seleccionado.");
                }
            }
            else{
                rejected("No se poseen datos para generar archivo excel en el rango de fechas seleccionado.");
            }
        });
    }
```

```
// Con este código solicito permisos
static async tienePermisoEscritura() {
        try {
            if (Platform.OS === 'android') {
                const permisoEscribir = await PermissionsAndroid.check(PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);

                if (permisoEscribir) {
                    return true;
                }
                else {
                    const permisoSolicitado = await PermissionsAndroid.request(
                        PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
                        {
                            title: "Permisos Mi Asistente de Negocios",
                            message: "La aplicación requiere permisos para acceder al almacenamiento del dispositivo.",
                            buttonNegative: "Negar permisos",
                            buttonPositive: "Conceder permisos"
                        }
                    );

                    if (permisoSolicitado == PermissionsAndroid.RESULTS.GRANTED) {
                        return true;
                    }
                    else {
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            }
            else
                if (Platform.OS === 'ios') {
                    return false;
                }
        }
        catch (err) {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

```
// Está función me devuelve el directorio donde se guardan los archivos
static get DirectorioMAN() {
        if (Platform.OS === 'android') {
            return `${fs.ExternalStorageDirectoryPath}/Documents`;
        }
        else {
            return `${fs.LibraryDirectoryPath}/Mi Asistente de Negocios`;
        }
    }
```

Hice unos console log para que vieran que la ruta donde se guarda el archivo excel es misma donde indico que va a ir a buscar el archivo para intentar abrirlo.

[image: Salida Consola]

Si voy a ver el archivo que me generó en la carpeta Documents, la ruta es igual a la que consulto yo.

[image: Ruta del archivo en el teléfono]

Comment: Hmmm... ¿Leíste [esta issue](https://github.com/vinzscam/react-native-file-viewer/issues/13) en el repo de _react-native-file-viewer_?

Comment: No me he topado con la issue, no me había dado cuenta gracias, la leeré

Comment: Si en esa issue está la respuesta a tu pregunta, no olvides responderla aquí y [aceptarla](/help/accepted-answer) :)

Comment: Hola, al fin pude resolver mi problema, gracias por postear esa issue, pero el verdadero problema no fue esa issue, pero la issue que posteaste me llevo a otro lugar, porque después de hacer lo que indicaban allí dio otro error y poco a poco llegue  a donde quería

Tuve que agregar lo que indican acá
https://github.com/vinzscam/react-native-file-viewer/issues/23#issuecomment-1019828334

a mi AndroidManifies.xml

Comment: Se tuvo que añadir esto al archivo antes mencionado

    ...
  </application>
+ <queries>
+   <intent>
+     <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
+     <!-- If you don't know the MIME type in advance, set "mimeType" to "*/*". -->
+     <data android:mimeType="application/pdf" />
+   </intent>
+ </queries>
</manifest>

Antes no usaba eso porque no había problema, pero ahora tuve que usarlo
https://github.com/vinzscam/react-native-file-viewer#mostly-automatic-installation-recommended

El código lo deje exactamente igual.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El verdadero problema si no me equivoco, esto no está probado todavía en varios teléfonos pero funciona al menos en los que probé [Link del problema](https://github.com/vinzscam/react-native-file-viewer/issues/23#issuecomment-1019828334) el código se quedo exactamente igual, pero en Android hay que modificar el archivo android/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml

Abajo de donde se cierra la etiqueta 
hay que añadir

```
    ...
</aplication>
<queries>
        <intent>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
<!-- el mimeType"*/*" es para indicar si el archivo que se desea abrir se desconoce el tipo. -->
        <data android:mimeType="*/*" />
        </intent>
</queries>
</manifiest>
```

Nota: en el teléfono virtual no funciona está solución, solo funciona en teléfonos físicos, en algunos telefonos virtuales si funciona por ejemplo Pixel 2, pero tienen que tener habilitado lo de la play stored y tener instalada una aplicación que habrá el archivo que se desea abrir.

Comment: Qué bueno que hayas encontrado respuesta. Por cierto, ¿el nombre del archivo es _AndroidManifies.xml_ o _AndroidManifest.xml_?

Comment: Oh, no me di cuenta, lo voy a corregir jaja, gracias de nuevo.